# insert part of link via text box, form - get profile picture on click?

Tags: php, facebook, image, forms, hyperlink

I only know ccs and html so the following is quite hard for me to do and understand

Im wanting a text box form that a user can enter a facebook user id, press a button and load the profile picture in a frame or something next to the button.

I know there a bit about this on here ive had a pretty good look around but not know php hasn't helped

I was thinking the "text box form" should somehow insert the **User ID** on button click into the code below? i also wanted the profiles name ? but don't want to get too ahead of myself :)

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/User ID/picture" alt="Profile Picture" height ="42" width="42">
```

As I've said i don't know too much, so any help would be amazing especially in simple terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get the user profile picture this way:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture
```

You were quite close:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture" 
     alt="Profile Picture" height ="42" width="42">
```

And more info about him this way:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID
```

Use `curl` or `file_get_content` in PHP to retrieve the requested content.

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't really what i was asking, but still thanks for your time :) (the link was wrong by on purpose to help people understand what i was talking aout

Comment: Then I will let you learn the very basics of PHP... you can't just ask something in a language if you don't know how to use [variables and forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php).

Comment: Hey i've just tried using file_get_content it works fine, my question was and still is how can i let the website user input the user_id to get the profile picture?

Comment: [this](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php), [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm) or
[this](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php).